# error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"

Tags: c++

I have this error:

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"

with this code example:

[image]

Comment: Please put the code in this question.  As text, not a picture of text.  Questions often get closed if they are mostly on other websites or not in a format that a compiler could understand.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `NTSTATUS` is not defined, so the compiler is *assuming* the function returns an `int` instead.

Add `#include <Ntdef.h>`.  Or, just use `LONG` instead, which is what `NTSTATUS` maps to.

Comment: thz so much and it woked also how i fix this "unresolved external symbol "int_cdcel CleanProcess(void)" (?CleanProccess@@YAHXZ)"
code is std::thread t1(VanguardDrivers);
 t1.detach();

 std::thread t2(ProcessKiller);
 t2.detach();

 std::thread t3(GayMacChanger);
 t3.detach();

 std::thread t4(DriverLoad);
 Sleep(7000);
 t4.detach();

 std::thread t5(CleanProcess);
 t5.detach();

 std::thread t6(CleanCaches);
 t6.detach();

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/) You have *declared* `CleanProcess()` but have not *defined* it, ie the linker can't find its implementation, either because you didn't write one yet, or you are not compiling/linking the `.cpp` file that does.

Comment: but i put int CleanProcess(); because the int CleanProcess() in a clean.c file  so i put that so the int clean can call it and i can use it in the main.cpp file

Comment: `int CleanProcess();` is a *declaration*, not a *definition*. The linker is complaining about a missing *definition*. The filename `clean.c` implies that file *may* get compiled as C code, not as C++ code. If that is the case, then either tell the compiler to compile the file as C++ instead, or change its name to `clean.cpp`, or else try applying `extern "C"` to the *declaration*.

Comment: it starts to compile then it stops at 1>Generating code do u know fix?

Comment: That is not a helpful description. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error.